# Блок информации кандидата в модераторы

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, выборы

На [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=nomination) по прошедшему в 2015 году голосованию по выбору модераторов в блоке отображения информации кандидатов имеются ошибка. Пример внешнего вида блока:

> [image: кандидат]

Проблемы:

1. Строка с временем размещения пересекает вертикальную черту;
2. Ошибка в склонении: "участник 1 года";
3. Ошибка в числе: "баллы кандидатов". Должно быть "баллы кандидата";
4. Несогласованное использование двоеточий в списке:

   - есть двоеточие: знаки модерации, знаки за редактирование;
   - нет двоеточия: репутация, <s>знаки участия,</s> заголовок (баллы).

Для сравнения блок на enSO:

> [image: enSO кандидат]

Comment: Пункт 3 пофиксил в транзифексе. 4 тоже можно, но лучше через оригинальные строки. 1 и 2 требуют участия разработчиков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил перевод по пункту 2 на *"участник в течение $memberFor$"*:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/9177

В таком виде лучше согласуется с длительностью, отображаемой при обычном просмотре профиля участника. Более длинный текст перевода автоматически исправляет проблему под пунктом 1.

Должно отразиться на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.3.12.38768