# Ok ли 0k в плашке репутации?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, репутация, выборы

Смотрю на вот это:

[image: скриншот]

Во-первых, в надписи

> репутация: 0k

запись "0k" воспринимается мной как "OK", а не как "0 тыс".

Во-вторых, можно было и поточнее написать: "556".
Кстати, по идее 556 округляется в большую сторону, а не в меньшую.

Comment: Каждая полная тысяча репутации даёт один балл кандидата, считать удобно: просто сложив четыре цифры. Поэтому мне кажутся хорошими варианты:  0/20 или как сейчас 0к. Спутать можно, а вот если был пробел между "0" и "k" было бы гораздо разборчивее.

Comment: @AK, я 5 минут искал, где же в плашке его репутация :(

Comment: Репутация норм. Знаки модерации o_O

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для нас очень неожиданно увидеть кандидатов в модераторы с репутацией меньше 1000. Скорее всего из-за этого о такой проблеме до сих пор и не сообщалось.

Я добавил логику проверки для отображения в таких случаях точного значения.

Изменения появятся в следующей версии (сейчас 2017.10.13.27422).

---

It is highly unusually for us to see moderator election candidates with reputation under 1,000 - which is likely why this has not been reported before.

I've added logic to check for this condition and display the full reputation in such cases.

This will be up after the current revision (rev 2017.10.13.27422).

Comment: If you have made an automatically translation from Russian to English in the question, would you like to translate your answer to Russian this way? P.S. Just for fun :)

Comment: I don't have the option inside Chrome. I could go through the translate site, but... this is better done by people :P

Comment: @alexolut, I'll translate. UPDATE: done.

Comment: @Oded we didn't expect that as well. :)

Comment: Booooring......

Comment: [Not good enough](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6103/176217)

Comment: Could you please also have a look [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4069/176217) for all items except 3. Item 3 just fixed in Transifex by me.