# Отображение репутации менее 1000 для кандидата в модераторы (часть вторая)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, репутация, выборы

[Предыдущий фикс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6098/176217) не удался, товарищ Oded!

> [image: not 0k]

Перевод для "reputation" я уже добавил. Как обычно, надо ждать Николаса и пересборки.

Comment: Кстати, а может "<1k" сделать?

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда будет `<2/40` ;)

Comment: В самый раз \*ROFL*

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас, кстати, получается, это самый рейтинговый кандидат!

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще, конечно, учитывая, что для большой репы пишется  `>= 20k`, сделать  `< 1k` выглядит вполне консистентным решением.

Comment: Достойный баг для пятницы  тринадцатое!

Comment: _"Перевод для "reputation" я уже добавил"_ - кажется, у тебя тоже не получилось?

Comment: @Qwertiy помимо факта перевода, нужно еще [дернуть](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40534645#40534645) и после дождаться пересборки. Видимо чего-то из этого не произошло еще.

Comment: @alexolut, у тебя в чате был скриншот "участник с 2 лет", но сейчас этого косяка нет, значит, уже дёрнули, значит, с reputation не вышло?

Comment: @Qwertiy с "с" был не косяк, а "элегантное" [решение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40536210#40536210) через правку на клиентской части :-D

Comment: @alexolut, значит я вообще то место в чате не понял. Я поржал над регистрацией двухлетнего ребёнка и решил, что это неудачный вариант перевода :)

Comment: @Qwertiy это "попытка" решить проблему с падежами при указании длительности "дня/дней, года/лет, месяца/месяцев".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ответ на аналогичный баг-репорт [прозвучал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302116/339911) на MSE:

В переводе:

> В попытке исправить другую проблему сломалось здесь.
>   Сейчас всё исправлено.

P.S. Ну, мы так и думали :)