# Формулировка времени проведенном на сайте на странице пользователя

Tags: дефект, локализация, даты

У меня на странице можно увидеть такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли обработка какая-то чисел в данном месте, я думаю что лучше будет "лет" а не "года".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему используются вот эти [строки](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5C%24__count%5C%24%20years%24). Подправил переводы для случаев one и few  (2-4).

Так же пришлось подкорректировать перевод в [блоке кандидатов в модераторы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11426/176217). Так как там используются те же строки.

Возможно вылезет ещё какое-то место, где требуется разделение контекстов и, следовательно, без участия разработчиков не обойтись. Например, есть вот такой случай: [Same strings in different contexts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288810/339911) (уже более 4х лет не исправляется).

Переводы должны подхватиться в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.3.12.38768